How do i conditional format my excel sheet based on conditions in 2 different columns?
I have an excel sheet with several columns. Column b contains dates - several rows could contain the same date. Column c contains a series of values for each date (30, 20, 45, etc).
I want to highlight the cells in column c when they total 120 and only when the dates in column b are the same.
For example b1:b4 are all "05/25/2024" and c1:c4 are 30, 30, 40, 20 then cells c1:c4 would be highlighted. Following, If b2 contained a different date then c1:c4 would not highlight despite totalling 120.

This should work assuming the first row with data is row 2 and ends in row 999. Put this as the conditional format  formula =SUMIF($B$2:$B$999,B2,$C$2:$C$999)>120

I would suggest defining all rules in a separate cell (it's easier to maintain it and troubleshoot) and using the value of that cell to conditionally format the required cells.
For example, E3 could have the following formula:
=AND(
    AND(EXACT(B2:B5,B2)),
    SUM(C2:C5)=120)=TRUE

And your conditional formatting rules would be as simple as

